# Specifying frameworks and weak_frameworks in CocoaPods podspec don't seem to work

Tags: objective-c, frameworks, cocoapods, static-libraries, xcode8

I specified frameworks ad weak_frameworks for my private pod but after installing it via pod install, I am not seeing AdSupport or WebKit appearing anywhere in the project settings.

Should it appear under Build Phases -> Link Binary with Libraries or Build Settings -> Linker Flags? What's the difference between the two?

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name             = 'Analytics'
  s.version          = '1.0.0'
  s.summary          = 'Analytics SDK'
  s.description      = <<-DESC
Analytics SDK
                       DESC

  s.homepage         = 'https://github.com/author/analytics-ios'
  s.license          = ''
  s.author           = { 'Author' => 'Email' }
  s.source           = { :git => 'https://github.com/author/analytics-ios.git', :tag => s.version.to_s }
  s.vendored_frameworks = 'Pods/Assets/Analytics.framework'
  s.ios.deployment_target = '9.0'
  s.frameworks       = 'AdSupport'
  s.weak_frameworks = 'WebKit'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the reference to those frameworks on your respective `.xcconfig` file associated to your target. In the `Pods` folder within your main Xcode project structure.